# Get ID and Value from a checkbox: Return to model and use in method to insert into sql database

Tags: javascript, html, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to create a checkbox list where a user is supposed to be able to choose one or more options, based on the choice: this is supposed to be inserted to a database table, where the id of the choice is inserted. (This is on a page where a user can "edit garage"), therefore the `garageid` is also supposed to be fetched and both the `garageid` and the `choice id` should be inserted to a cross table, that I have created as following:

```
   [ID]
  ,[GarageID]
  ,[RequestProperty]
  ,[CreatedDate]
  ,[CreatedBy]
  ,[UpdatedDate]
  ,[UpdatedBy]
```

I also have a stored procedure for the insert:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[spGarageGetRequestTypes]
    -- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here

    @GarageID INT,
    @RequestType INT

AS
BEGIN
    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
    -- interfering with SELECT statements.
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    INSERT INTO GarageCrossRequestType
    (GarageID, RequestProperty)
    VALUES (@GarageID, @RequestType)
    
END
```

And the "edit page" is working and functioning, it's where I get the `garageId` as well. It looks like following in view:

```
<div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Garage</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-lg-10 form-control" name="GarageName" id="GarageName" placeholder="Name" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Contact person</label>
                    <input type="text" class="col-lg-10 form-control" name="ContactPerson" id="ContactPerson" placeholder="ContactPerson" required="" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="row">
                    <label class="col-xs-2 control-label">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" class="col-lg-10 form-control" name="Email" id="Email" placeholder="Email" required="" onblur="validateEmail(this.value);" /><p id="InvalidMeg" style="font-size: 25px; color: red">Invalid e-mail address</p>
                </div>
            </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
function editGarage(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
            var garageId = dataItem.GarageId;
            countryId = dataItem.CountryId;
        var email = dataItem.Email;
            var contactperson = dataItem.ContactPerson;
            if (garageId != 0) {
                $("#EditGarageBtn").show();
                $("#saveNewGarageBtn").hide();
                $("#GarageName").val(name);
                $("#Country").val(countryId);
                $("#ContactPerson").val(contactperson);
                $("#Email").val(email);
              
            }
        }

 $("#EditGarageBtn").click(function () {
            var customerNumber = customerNumberOfEditingGarage;

            name = $("#GarageName").val();
            countryId = $("#Country").val();
            var garageId = $("#garageId").val();
            var contactperson = $("#ContactPerson").val();
            var email = $("#Email").val();
            $("#EditGarageBtn").hide();

            if (name.length > 0 && email.length > 0 && contactperson.length > 0) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("EditGarage", "Garage")',
                dataType: 'JSON',
                data: {
                    name: name, countryId: countryId, garageId: garageId, 
                    contactperson: contactperson, email: email
                },
                success: function (data) {
                    if (data == "Failure") {
                        toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
                    }
                    else {
                        toastr["success"]("Garage successfully updated");
                        customerNumberOfEditingGarage = null;
                        refreshGrid();
                    }
                },
                error: function () {

                }
            });
            } else {
                toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
            }
        });

</script>
```

Model:

```
 public class GarageModel
    {
        public int GarageTypeId { get; set; }
        public int CountryId { get; set; }
        public string ContactPerson { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public int GarageId { get; set; }


    // for the choices in the checkbox
    public int ScheduledService { get; set; } = 1;
        public int Tires { get; set; } = 2;
    }
```

Method:

```
public bool EditGarage(GarageModel model)
        {
            var valid = false;

            var cmd = new SqlCommand("spGarageEditGarage", Connection);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CountryId", model.CountryId);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", model.Name);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContactPerson", model.ContactPerson);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Email", model.Email);
            try
            {

                int result = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (result == 1)
                    valid = true;
            }

            catch (SqlException ex)
            {
                throw new Exception(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                Connection.Close();
            }


        // for the choices in the checkbox (not working!)
            List<int> newlist = new List<int>();
            newlist.Add(model.Tires);
            newlist.Add(model.ScheduledService);

            foreach (var item in newlist)
            {
                if (newlist != null)
                {
                    var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spGarageGetRequestTypes", Connection);
                    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
                    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestType", newlist.First());

                    int result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
                    if (result == 1)
                        valid = true;
                }
            }

            return valid;
        }
```

If you look at my comments in the model and the method, you can see what I've added for the "choices" function I'm trying to implement. Here's the html i created for the input type as well:

```
@foreach (var items in Model)
                    {
                        <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label class="ab">Tires</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.Tires" id="Tires" placeholder="Tires" required="" value="@items.Tires" />
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class='form-group' style="margin-left: 60%;">
                            <div class="row">
                                <label class="ab">Scheduled Service</label>
                                <input type="checkbox" class="checkbclass" name="@items.ScheduledService" id="Scheduled" placeholder="Scheduled" required="" value="@items.ScheduledService" />

                            </div>
                        </div>
                    }
```

Now, to the problems:

1: I need some sort of method for making sure which or if a checkbox is checked, and this needs to be returned to the model or controller in some way. I only want to return it's numeric value, as seen in the model I want Tires to have the numeric value of 2 etcetera.

2. The datebase insert works (so at least that's something), but the table only accepts `RequestProperty` and `GarageID`, meaning that if a user chooses 2 of the checkboxes, I need to update the database twice, creating 2 rows, but with the same `garageid`.

I tried posting a question about this earlier, but it was poorly explained from my side, so I'm trying again, and hoping I included everything this time. I'm open to any help/solutions that can help me solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, You need to remove all `GarageCrossRequestType` that containe current `GarageID` as the checkbox may be `checked` and `unhacked` later on edit.

This how I would do it.

Note: make sure to read the comment

### javascript

```js
$("#EditGarageBtn").click(function() {
  var customerNumber = customerNumberOfEditingGarage;
  // I assumed that you want name as the int of RequestType eg 1 or 2 that are checked
  var garageCrossRequestType = $(".checkbclass:checked").map(function(x) {
   return   parseInt($(x).attr("name"));
   });
  name = $("#GarageName").val();
  countryId = $("#Country").val();
  var garageId = $("#garageId").val();
  var contactperson = $("#ContactPerson").val();
  var email = $("#Email").val();
  $("#EditGarageBtn").hide();

  if (name.length > 0 && email.length > 0 && contactperson.length > 0) {
    $.ajax({
      url: '@Url.Action("EditGarage", "Garage")',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      data: {
        name: name,
        countryId: countryId,
        garageId: garageId,
        contactperson: contactperson,
        email: email,
        garageCrossRequestType: garageCrossRequestType // here send the checked checkedboxes
      },
      success: function(data) {
        if (data == "Failure") {
          toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
        } else {
          toastr["success"]("Garage successfully updated");
          customerNumberOfEditingGarage = null;
          refreshGrid();
        }
      },
      error: function() {

      }
    });
  } else {
    toastr["error"]("Error editing Garage");
  }
});
```

### C#

```js
// create an sqlProcedure or something instead of this, this is only to show how it work
// You have to clear all GarageCrossRequestType that containe the current GarageID
// An after insert the newly checked items
new SqlCommand("delete GarageCrossRequestType where GarageID = " + model.GarageId, Connection).ExecuteNonQuery();
List <int> newlist = new List<int>();
if (model.garageCrossRequestType != null)
    newlist.AddRange(model.garageCrossRequestType);
  foreach(var item in newlist) {
    //newlist cant be null becouse you are already in a loop. 
    // and also newlist is never null
    // if (newlist != null)

    var cmd1 = new SqlCommand("spGarageGetRequestTypes", Connection);
    cmd1.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GarageId", model.GarageId);
    // instead of newlist.First() you are looping throw newlist eg checkboxes then it should be item
    cmd1.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RequestType", item);

    int result = cmd1.ExecuteNonQuery();
    if (result == 1)
      valid = true;

  }
```

Comment: I like this solution, but I get an error that x.attr is not a function. And I wonder what your idea about model.garageCrossRequestType as I do not have this in my model right now? :)

Comment: I updated the answer about `attr` it should work now. about `garageCrossRequestType` you could add it as a List of int, or simple remove it and assign `ScheduledService ` and `Tires` instead is up to you. But this should help you understand how this should work. Personality I would use  `garageCrossRequestType` as there seems to be more then two checkboxes in the future.

Comment: I created a list of int, thank you. However, the attr still does not seem to work, it throws an: cannot convert undefiend or null to objectmajor error..

Comment: Hhh comeon it should work, it is a simple .map operation. Figure out what is wrong.

Comment: i know it should work! i'll see if i can try to figure out whats wrong

Comment: I managed to find a solution, returning $(this).val(); fixed it. I'm still not able to get the values to the controller, but when using console.log i can see that the values are being sent so at least that's something haha. I can reward your bounty in 2 hours, thanks for the help!

Comment: Just to update: Everything works great now, adding type: POST in the ajax called fixed it! So again thank you so much for the help, I'm not used to working with JavaScript so the help was much needed!

Comment: Glad I could help, with practice you would be good at JavaScript. Maybe its also time to work with react to make this much simple in the future.